# EF core 3.0 Identity column and ValueConverter

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This my entity:

```
public class Audit
{
    public string Pk { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string RowPk { get; set; }
    public string ActionType { get; set; }
    public string RowContent { get; set; }
}
```

This my mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Audit>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.Pk).IsClustered(true);
    entity.Property(e => e.Pk)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
    .UseIdentityColumn()
    .HasConversion(new ValueConverter<string, long>(v => Convert.ToInt64(v),v => Convert.ToString(v)));

    entity.Property(e => e.TableName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
    entity.Property(e => e.RowPk).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
    entity.Property(e => e.ActionType).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(1);
    entity.Property(e => e.RowContent).IsRequired;
});
```

My requirements:

Audit.Pk: `string`
Pk column: `BigInt` and `AutoIncrement`

Adding the migration I get the following error:

> Identity value generation cannot be used for the property 'Pk' on
>   entity type 'Audit' because the property type is 'string'. Identity
>   value generation can only be used with signed integer properties.

Any workaround?

Comment: Is I correctly understand that you want to use one collumn as Primary and Foreign keys?

Comment: How can the database auto increase a `string`?

Comment: DB column of type bigint not string that is because I use converter

Comment: The error message speaks about **property** type, not db column type. Consider it current EF Core limitation/shortcoming - value generators and value converters cannot be used together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally speaking, the `string` is not a common data type for `primary key`. most of the time we use `int` or `GUID`. for solving your problem you can use below snippet:

```
public class Audit
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int Id { get; set; }  //instead of Pk 

   [NotMapped]
   public string Pk => Id.ToString();


   .  
   .
   .
}
```

And finally, Remove all related code to `Pk` property from your mapping

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a bigint primary key is easier to maintain for your SQL tables. Otherwise, change your primary key `PK` to something like a GUID.

Otherwise, I advise the following change to your class is having a PkString is mandatory in your program (this change is transparent to your database) :

```
public class Audit
{
    [Key]
    public long Pk { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string PkString => Pk.ToString();

    public string TableName { get; set; }

    public string RowPk { get; set; }

    public string ActionType { get; set; }

    public string RowContent { get; set; }
}
```